# lightgallery.js with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, lightgallery

I'm trying to run the [lightgallery.js](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/) script (pure JS version) using querySelectorAll in several classes to no avail.

This is the code I'm using:

```
var lg = document.querySelectorAll( '.gallery-1, .gallery-2, .gallery-3');
for ( var i = 0; i < lg.length; i++ ) {
    lightGallery( lg[i], {
        selector: '.gallery-item > a:has(img)',
        mode: 'lg-fade',
        preload: 2,
        counter: false,
        download: false
    });
}
```

I'm getting a "lightGallery has not initiated properly" error in the console. Before, I was using the jQuery version of the lightgallery script with no problems using `$( '.gallery-1, .gallery-2, .gallery-3' ).lightGallery()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was the `:has()` used in the `selector` option in the script. `:has()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification and, thus, cannot be used in pure JS scripts.

**UPDATE:**

This is the code I'm using now:

```
var lg = document.querySelectorAll( '.gallery-1, .gallery-2, .gallery-3');
for ( var i = 0; i < lg.length; i++ ) {
    lightGallery( lg[i], {
        selector: '.gallery-item > a[href$=".jpg"], .gallery-item > a[href$=".jpeg"], .gallery-item > a[href$=".png"], .gallery-item > a[href$=".gif"]',
        mode: 'lg-fade',
        preload: 2,
        counter: false,
        download: false
    });
}
```

Comment: So  what is the code that fixed the problem ?If you solved the problem it would be good to post the relevant code in your answer. This way others might find it helpful :)